# What should I do about questions that have a wrong preconception already in them

Tags: discussion, questions

An example might be: "Why is the sky neon green?"

What should I do with such questions? Close as off-topic? Close as unclear? Downvote? Answer with (in this case) "It isn't, it's blue most of the time"?

<sup><sub>I vaguely remember seeing a question about this but couldn't find it with a search, apologies if this has already been asked.</sub></sup>